# Use Variable Inside Comparison String

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, typescript, react-hooks

I am using this imy code but instead of hard-coding `d@d.com`, I want to use the variable email. I tried `$(email)`& `${email}`but it didn't work.

```
if(errorMessage=='Key (email)=(d@d.com) already exists.')
```

Edit:

```
export default function AddUserPage() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    loggedIn: false,
  });

  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [added, setAdded] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  function StatusMessage() {
    if (added) {
      console.log('User Added');
      return (
        <Alert className="alerts" severity="success">
          User Added
        </Alert>
      );
    } else {
      console.log('Really');
      if (errorMessage == `GraphQL error: Key (email)=${email} already exists.`) {
        return (
          <Alert className="alerts" severity="error">
            Email Already Exists In Database
          </Alert>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <Alert className="alerts" severity="error">
            Not Added
          </Alert>
        );
      }
    }
  }

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if(added){
  //     StatusMessage();
  //   }
  // },[added] );

  function submitForm(AddUserMutation: any) {
    setSubmitted(true);
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password, phoneNumber } = state;
    if (firstName && lastName && email && password && phoneNumber) {
      AddUserMutation({
        variables: {
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          email: email,
          password: password,
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        },
      })
        .then(({ data }: any) => {
          setAdded(true);
          console.log('ID: ', data.createUser.id);
        })
        .catch((error: { message: string }) => {
          console.log('Error msg:' + error.message);
          setErrorMessage(error.message);
        });
      // .catch(console.log)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Mutation mutation={AddUserMutation}>
      {(AddUserMutation: any) => (
        <div>
          <PermanentDrawerLeft></PermanentDrawerLeft>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{ firstName: '', lastName: '', email: '', password: '', phoneNumber: '' }}
            onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                actions.setSubmitting(false);
              }, 1000);
            }}
            validationSchema={schema}
          >
            {props => {
              const {
                values: { firstName, lastName, email, password, phoneNumber },
                errors,
                touched,
                handleChange,
                isValid,
                setFieldTouched,
              } = props;
              const change = (name: string, e: any) => {
                e.persist();
                handleChange(e);
                setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
                setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: e.target.value }));
              };
              return (
                <div className="main-content">
                  <form
                    style={{ width: '100%' }}
                    onSubmit={e => {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      submitForm(AddUserMutation);
                      StatusMessage();
                    }}
                  >
                    <div>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        id="firstName"
                        name="firstName"
                        helperText={touched.firstName ? errors.firstName : ''}
                        error={touched.firstName && Boolean(errors.firstName)}
                        label="First Name"
                        value={firstName}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, 'firstName')}
                      />
                      <br></br>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        id="lastName"
                        name="lastName"
                        helperText={touched.lastName ? errors.lastName : ''}
                        error={touched.lastName && Boolean(errors.lastName)}
                        label="Last Name"
                        value={lastName}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, 'lastName')}
                      />
                      <br></br>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        id="email"
                        name="email"
                        helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ''}
                        error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                        label="Email"
                        value={email}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, 'email')}
                      />
                      <br></br>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                        helperText={touched.password ? errors.password : ''}
                        error={touched.password && Boolean(errors.password)}
                        label="Password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, 'password')}
                      />{' '}
                      &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      <VisibilityIcon></VisibilityIcon>
                      <br></br>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        id="phoneNumber"
                        name="phoneNumber"
                        helperText={touched.phoneNumber ? errors.phoneNumber : ''}
                        error={touched.phoneNumber && Boolean(errors.phoneNumber)}
                        label="Phone Number"
                        value={phoneNumber}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, 'phoneNumber')}
                      />
                      <br></br>
                      <Button
                        type="submit"
                        disabled={!isValid || !email || !password}
                        style={{
                          background: '#6c74cc',
                          borderRadius: 3,
                          border: 0,
                          color: 'white',
                          height: 48,
                          padding: '0 30px',
                        }}
                      >
                        Add User
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                  <br></br>
                  {submitted && StatusMessage()}
                  {/* <Typography>Message: {errorMessage}</Typography> */}
                </div>
              );
            }}
          </Formik>
        </div>
      )}
    </Mutation>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (note the backticks):

```
if(errorMessage === `Key (email)=${email} already exists.`)
```

If you don't care about exact text matching, you can check for the error message with `includes`:

```
if(errorMessage.includes('already exists')
```

Comment: In my case this just say cannot find name email

Comment: Ok, I see. Matching by error messages like this is a bad idea. You'd return proper message from the api instead.

Comment: The api does return a proper message (see .catch), but I need to render messages according to what the error message is

Comment: @a125 still think it's better to make a loose check. Updated the answer.

Comment: This works but there's one issue. At first it automatically renders the else case saying ``User Not Added``Then it is automatically changed to the correct case```Email Already Exists In Database```. Any idea why the wrong one is rendered at first?

Comment: The errorMessage is empty on the first render and `added` is false so it goes straight to the else clause in the `StatusMessage`. You probably need to check if the error message isn't empty before rendering status message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(errorMessage === `Key (email)=${state.email} already exists.`)
```